# How can I use pandas assign to create a new column with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, assign

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

```
Date, Variable 1, rank_pct
```

I am trying to use assign to create a new column called "ls" that has 1, -1, or 0 in it.

1. If the rank_pct is <0.10, put a 1 in the column ls
2. If the rank_pct is >0.90, put a -1 in the column ls.
3. If the rank_pct is anything else, put a 0 in the column.

I don't want to use a for loop to iterate through each row in the rank_pct column, and I have already tried the following (which returns a column with True/False:

```
data = data.assign(ls= data['rank_pct']<.10)
```

Is there any command I can put inside the parentheses to convert the T/F into 1, -1, and 0?

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data.assign(ls=np.where(data.rank_pct<.1, 1,
                        np.where(data.rank_pct>.9, -1, 0)))
```